# Redirect cronjob output to http instead of https joomla

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

A little stuck as coding isn't my thing but thought i'd ask, ive trolled through google and stackoverflow but can't find an answer that works. I need to redirect https://www.doughillardsports.co.uk/index.php?option=com_akeeba&view=check&key=SrTB8WWQMjqq4yAQaiVQn4McsfShfplP to http in the      .htaccess file. here is my code.

```
## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed   below
 # This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.doughillardsports.co.uk/index.php?    option=com_akeeba&view=check&key=SrTB8WWQMjqq4yAQaiVQn4McsfShfplP [R=301,L]
```

Any help will be great if you an help at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve HTTP by using the below, it will force HTTP on all if HTTPS is on.

```
RewriteEngine On

#Check to see if HTTPS, if so, make HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It's just for one url not all. will that still work.

Comment: When you say for the one URL, do you mean the one domain or for specific directory? If it is for the one domain, the above will work fine. If you need it for a specific directory only, then we just need to change the `RewriteRule` to that specific directory.

Comment: so i've disabled force ssl on the site but that url needs to http as it checks our backup make sure its done. So to redirect everything http its the above code but making that single url i change the rule

Comment: That's right Alex :) The above will force all HTTPS connections to become HTTP. But if you only want to do that for a specific URL then all we need to do is specify that in the `RewriteRule`

Comment: RewriteEngine On     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST} !^\/index.php?option=com_akeeba&view=check&key=
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]